# Need to take a screenshot of the full browser window (non-headless) with Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, browser, capybara, screenshot

We're currently using capybara's `save_screenshot` to save objective evidence of test results. Works good in most scenarios. However we have some complex tests that involve switching browser tabs and diagnosing failures on those tests becomes difficult when the image we get from `save_screenshot` only contains the contents of the current tab.

Our ideal solution would be to take a screenshot of the entire browser window including the address bar and showing all the tabs that exist. Instead of re-creating the screen for a screenshot I want to take a physical screenshot as though a user pressed Print Screen. Obviously this would only work in a non-headless capacity, we're OK with that.

We're executing these tests inside a docker container so if there's something docker-y we can do that works too.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Comment: @anothermh What tag are you referring to? It's not clear to me what problem you are reporting.

Comment: Your original title was *Automation with Ruby (Capybara) - Need to take a screenshot of the full browser window (non-headless)*. That is forcing the tags *Ruby* and *Capybara* into the title. Write your titles in natural language.